# How to display validation message for select box in CakePHP 3?

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0, formhelper

Below you can see my model and view. Can't figure out how to display validation error message. How do I do that? All other validation messages for input fields are displayed as expected.

```php
class ProjectsTable extends Table {
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
        $validator->requirePresence('language');
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php echo $this->Form->select('language', [
    'option' => 'value',
    '' => 'Select'
], ['default' => '']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use `$this->Form->input()` instead of `select()`.

```php
<?php
$this->Form->input('language', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => [
         'option' => 'value'
    ]
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Validation errors are stored in entity and are accessed using `errors()` method.

```php
<?php echo $this->Form->select('language', [
    'option' => 'value',
    '' => 'Select'
], ['default' => '']); ?>

<?php foreach($project->errors('language') as $error):?>
    <div class="error-message"><?php echo $error;?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```